# Display CollectionViewCell in starting position

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I created a collection view cell with the Xib file. And I have only one cell, but that cell displaying in the center of the collectionView. I want to display cell at starting position of the collectionView.

I fixed **contentInset** in viewDidLoad and loading cell xib file here,

```
_listCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0 , 0, 0, 0);
```

And my cell size is

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    return  CGSizeMake(156,140);
}
```

Cell displaying like this.

[image]

Comment: can you add an attachment for the same

Comment: @ Er. Khatri, I attached image please check it.

Comment: By default collectionView alignment is center so if you have only single cell then try to align collectionView accordingly on view. (same size of collection view with cell) and it alignment with left of view

Comment: @ Pravin Tate, hot to fix it.

Comment: @ios as Pravin said, you change the width and height collection view to cell width and height. You can achieve this through programatically. If you are using auto layouts then give outlet connection to width and height and change its value.

Another way, you can use waterfall modal for collection view flow layout. There are many frame works are available for this. You can use them.

Answer (score 0):

Im not very clear with your question but i think what you are referring to is to align the collectionnView element to the view . You have to use `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` or `layoutAttributesforElements` to achieve this . Take look at the below code and to make if you want it in Objective c.

```
-(NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
NSArray *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect];

    CGFloat leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left; //initalized to silence compiler, and actaully safer, but not planning to use.
    CGFloat maxY = -1.0f;

    //this loop assumes attributes are in IndexPath order

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attribute in attributes) {
    if (attribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY) {
        leftMargin = self.sectionInset.left;
    }


     attribute.frame = CGRectMake(leftMargin, attribute.frame.origin.y, 
     attribute.frame.size.width, attribute.frame.size.height);

     leftMargin += attribute.frame.size.width + self.minimumInteritemSpacing;
     maxY = MAX(CGRectGetMaxY(attribute.frame), maxY);
    }

     return attributes;

    }
```

Comment: see my answer. it's simple and worked for me... Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `collectionView: cellForItemAtIndexPath:` function i made changes like this.

Here just i fixed my collectionviewcell **x origin position to 0** after loading the cell.

```
deviceCell= (DeviceCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DeviceCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

if (listArray.count == 1) {//Here i fixed the my cell x origin position
    CGRect frameRect = deviceCell.frame;//Copy cell frame
     frameRect.origin.x = 0;//Set cell origin.x
     deviceCell.frame = frameRect;//Reset frame
}
```